# DHCP fail with WEMOS D1 Mini in sagemcom FAST3890V3 router

Tags: c++, ip, router, esp8266, dhcp

with classic esp8266 (wemos) connection example usind DHCP in sagemcom FAST3890V3 router, i never get IP, after about 10 minutes i get some ip outside of range and it doesn't work.
I read lots of post and can't find a solution. thanks

connection pseudocode (you know)

```
 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  client.setTrustAnchors(&cert); // Add root certificate for api.telegram.org
 // wifi_station_set_auto_connect(true);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
```

wireshark capture only Discover - transaction, router didn't answer, 5 times.

323 43.461691   0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 DHCP    350 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x2beb89bf

Frame 323: 350 bytes on wire (2800 bits), 350 bytes captured (2800 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{4F87DED9-5E05-47A3-A4C3-1D594FD44EE5}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Espressi_df:9d:f6 (e8:db:84:df:9d:f6), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Destination: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
Address: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
.... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
.... ...1 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Group address (multicast/broadcast)
Source: Espressi_df:9d:f6 (e8:db:84:df:9d:f6)
Address: Espressi_df:9d:f6 (e8:db:84:df:9d:f6)
.... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
.... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0, Dst: 255.255.255.255
0100 .... = Version: 4
.... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
.... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
Total Length: 336
Identification: 0x0004 (4)
Flags: 0x00
0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
.0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
Fragment Offset: 0
Time to Live: 255
Protocol: UDP (17)
Header Checksum: 0xba99 [validation disabled]
[Header checksum status: Unverified]
Source Address: 0.0.0.0
Destination Address: 255.255.255.255
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68, Dst Port: 67
Source Port: 68
Destination Port: 67
Length: 316
Checksum: 0x5bed [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
[Stream index: 9]
[Timestamps]
UDP payload (308 bytes)
Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (Discover)
Message type: Boot Request (1)
Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
Hardware address length: 6
Hops: 0
Transaction ID: 0x2beb89bf
Seconds elapsed: 0
Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
Client IP address: 0.0.0.0
Your (client) IP address: 0.0.0.0
Next server IP address: 0.0.0.0
Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0
Client MAC address: Espressi_df:9d:f6 (e8:db:84:df:9d:f6)
Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
Server host name not given
Boot file name not given
Magic cookie: DHCP
Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Discover)
Length: 1
DHCP: Discover (1)
Option: (57) Maximum DHCP Message Size
Length: 2
Maximum DHCP Message Size: 1500
Option: (55) Parameter Request List
Length: 5
Parameter Request List Item: (1) Subnet Mask
Parameter Request List Item: (3) Router
Parameter Request List Item: (28) Broadcast Address
Parameter Request List Item: (6) Domain Name Server
Parameter Request List Item: (42) Network Time Protocol Servers
Option: (255) End
Option End: 255
Padding: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000…

0000   ff ff ff ff ff ff e8 db 84 df 9d f6 08 00 45 00
0010   01 50 00 04 00 00 ff 11 ba 99 00 00 00 00 ff ff
0020   ff ff 00 44 00 43 01 3c 5b ed 01 01 06 00 2b eb
0030   89 bf 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0040   00 00 00 00 00 00 e8 db 84 df 9d f6 00 00 00 00
0050   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0060   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0070   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0080   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0090   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00a0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00b0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00c0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00d0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00e0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00f0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0100   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0110   00 00 00 00 00 00 63 82 53 63 35 01 01 39 02 05
0120   dc 37 05 01 03 1c 06 2a ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0130   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0140   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0150   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: Did you try to print the IP to Serial?

Comment: i didn´t get an IP, DHCP negociation with sagemcom FAST3890V3 router is my problem. it didn´t fail with other routers.

Comment: try to analyze configurations in router then. It might be blocking your  device. adding to a white list may work, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you skipped it for security reasons but you need to store the SSID and password in respective variables to be used later in the connection loop, below is an example of a complete wifi configuration:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>        // Include the Wi-Fi library

const char* ssid     = "SSID";         // The SSID (name) of the Wi-Fi network you want to connect to
const char* password = "PASSWORD";     // The password of the Wi-Fi network

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);         // Start the Serial communication to send messages to the computer
  delay(10);
  Serial.println('\n');
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);             // Connect to the network
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid); Serial.println(" ...");

  int i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(++i); Serial.print(' ');
  }

  Serial.println('\n');
  Serial.println("Connection established!");  
  Serial.print("IP address:\t");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());         // Send the IP address of the ESP8266 to the computer
}

void loop() { }
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: hi, yes i put pseudo code, the esp8266 connect to router and fail to get an IP from DHCP, as you can see in the wireshark log. My code is similar to yours, this is not the problem, DHCP negociation with  sagemcom FAST3890V3 router is my problem. it didn´t fail with other routers.